# Customise the type hinting in PHP

Tags: php, types, type-conversion, strong-typing

I'm writing a **custom** extension system for php, which allows for defining a class with new function for an existing class, and add said functions to a class after its defined.

As said, extensions are written as a separate class, lets call one `MyExtension`, and lets say that this extension extends upon to existing classes, `MyExtendedClass1` and `MyExtendedClass2`. So `MyExtension` adds some functions to `MyExtendedClass1` AND `MyExtendedClass2`.

What I want to do is allow users to type hint base on MyExtension.

```
// $object is guaranteed to either be an instance of MyExtension
// or be a class that is extended with MyExtension
function someFunction(MyExtension $object) {

}
$post = new MyExtendedClass1(); // Is extended by MyExtension
someFunction($post);

$post = new MyExtendedClass2(); // Is extended by MyExtension
someFunction($post);
```

What I'm wondering is:

Is there any way to "add a type to an object"? Is there any way I can trick the type checking to allow these calls.

Comment: Does that not already work for you? [This is already supported behavior](http://codepad.org/05MBHxCl)

Comment: You can use as type hint `MyExtendedClass` since all `MyExtension` classes will extend `MyExtendedClass`.
Or for better, you can create an Interface that should implement all Extension classes and use that Interface for type hint.

Comment: In PHP this is known as **Type Hinting**. More info can be found on the PHP website: [Type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Comment: @castis I'm not talking about php's OOP `extends` feature, but rather a custom extension system that can add functionality to classes after there are defined

Comment: @akDeveloper I'v edited the question to use an example where this would not a applicable

Comment: @icecub My bad, fixed it.

Comment: Ok, now `someFunction` will accept instances of `MyExtension` class and any other class instance that extend `MyExtension`. 
Is there any reason you want to type hint child class and not the parent class?

Comment: @akDeveloper Read the first line, I've edited them. They should be clearer now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your question because you need *custom extension* descibed as *customly extended* object.

If you need **some_function** to operate on different types it can't use them directly and type hint can't determine concrete type - use **interface**.

Your types need to be extended with functionality of common interface that function can depend on - use wrapper objects that implement same inteface, but know (how to communicate) the concrete type.

```
interface MyExtensionInteface {
    public function doSoemthingSpecial();
}

function some_function(MyExtensionInterface $myExtension) {
    $myExtension->doSomethingSpecial();
}

class MyExtensionOfExtendedClass1 implements MyExtensionInteface
{
    public function __construct(MyExtendedClass1 $obj) {
        $this->extended = $obj;
    }

    public function doSomethingSpecial() {
        //...with MyExtendedClass1 type
    }
}

class MyExtensionOfExtendedClass2 impements MyExtensionInterface
{
     public function __construct(MyExtendedClass2 $obj) {
         $this->extended = $obj
     }

     public function doSomethingSpecial() {
         //...with MyExtendedClass2 type
     }
}

$a = new MyExtensionOfExtendedClass1(new MyExtendedClass1());
some_function($a);

$b = new MyExtensionOfExtendedClass2(new MyExtendedClass2());
some_function($b);
```

"Extension" naming is for question context only - it should have real object meaning. For example: `DuckSoup(Duck)` + `ChickenSoup(Chicken)` + `function:cook(Soup)`